# Single page React on Rails app vs Multi page React on Rails app

Tags: web-applications, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I've been looking around hoping to get some perspective of the pros and cons of using a Single Page React App vs. a Multi Page React App. The end product of the project is a page with 5 tabs, each having a form within it, with some of them having form dialogs.

We're using React on Rails. My initial thought was to allow each page be a React app.  I have a Rails engine which in its view is rendering the React apps. With a multi page app this was as simple as calling the requisite React App for each page. I am not sure how this will work in a Single Page App? It was suggested to use React Router but I haven't investigated how it will fit in with the Rails routes. Do we even need any routes in a SPA?

The other issue I am thinking of is how to handle so much state within a single page. I am assuming there will be a whole lot of action dispatching happening as the end user clicks on the different tabs. Are there any other issues I need to be aware of?